# Spring Security with JSF always return HTTP Status 404 when logging in

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I'm kinda new to Spring Security, i tried to view some tutorials, but most of them are talking about Spring web mvc + spring security, or spring + spring security, 
now i just want to add to my JSF application some role management, authentication and authorization which Spring Security provide very well.

Here is my login page:

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel value="username" for="j_username"
                   style="float:left" />
    <h:inputText id="j_username" style="float:left" />

    <h:outputLabel value="password" for="j_password"
                   style="float:left; clear:both" />
    <h:inputSecret id="j_password" style="float:left" />

    <h:commandButton value="login"
                     actionListener="#{loginController.login}" style="float:left;clear:both" />
</h:form>
```

my logging bean:

```
@Named(value = "loginController")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String login() throws ServletException, IOException {

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        externalContext.dispatch("/j_spring_security_check");
        facesContext.responseComplete();
        return null;
    }
```

and for my spring security file:

```
    <form-login login-page="/faces/login.xhtml" default-target-url="/faces/index.xhtml"
        authentication-failure-url="/faces/login.xhtml?status=failed"/> 
    <logout logout-success-url="/faces/logout.xhtml"/> 
</http>
```

and if for some reason someone wanted to look at my web.xml, here it is:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

One last thing, can Spring Security prevent users from navigating to "/index.xhtml" (instead of "/faces/index.xhtml") ? or maybe redirect them to the "/faces/..." if it is missing?

Comment: Not sure on Spring Security part as I don't do it, but you'd better replace `/faces/*` by `*.xhtml` and remove `faces/` prefix over all place so that you (and perhaps Spring Security) don't need to be bothered/confused by virtual URLs.

Comment: that didn't work for spring, but that kinda answer my second question thank you, and if you dont do Spring Security, how do you manages your users then?? the roles and permissions ... etc? I would love to hear from an expert like yourself.

Comment: Standard Java EE security APIs like JASPIC/JAAS, internally with help of utility library [OmniSecurity](http://omnisecurity.omnifaces.org) (which is still an Alpha project, we still need to work on documentation/tutorials and such).

Comment: Or try [PicketLink](http://www.picketlink.org) works nicely